# Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

According to the Spring Documentation [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/):

> While HTTP defines these four methods, HTML only supports two: GET and POST. Fortunately, there are two possible workarounds: you can either use JavaScript to do your PUT or DELETE, or simply do a POST with the 'real' method as an additional parameter (modeled as a hidden input field in an HTML form).

They have done the latter, and can be achieved with the following spring MVC form tag:

```
<form:form method="delete">
   <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form:form>
```

The problem is when i click 'Delete' my page throws the following error:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I changed the debug level of `org.springframework.web` to debug and found the following message:

```
DEBUG AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [foo.bar.MessageForm@da9246]:
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I used [RestClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9780/) with DELETE method and the method is called as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried POST as a parameter using RestClient and returned a Status Code: 405 method not allowed. Where could the problem be?

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: @hisdrewness yes I can, but I don't think the problem is in the Controller's url-mapping since using RestClient works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure HiddenHttpMethodFilter in your web.xml

Details can be found [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/):

Comment: I configured the filter and placed the filter-mapping to contain the <servlet-mapping> of the Spring MVC Dispatcher, but still didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: changed the <servlet-mapping> to <url-pattern>*</..> and it worked out fine. It seems using urlrewrite is part of the problem since when i tried <url-pattern>app/*</..> this filter get's validated first before the urlrewrite filter. Thanks maximdim!